# addClass is not functioning when I moved the code to a file separate fromt he $(document).ready(function()){})

Tags: jquery, css

I have a code snippet that I will be using across numerous pages. This code is used for updating the column headers in a table to show if a column is sorted ascending or descending. 
I would like to place in a separate .js file rather than duplicating it across all pages. The snippet works correctly when it is within the 
$("body").on("click") function. When I move it to its own function and call that function, the script executes, however the results of the addClass/removeClass don't persist to the web page. Any assistance would be appreciated. I am quite new to JQuery and haven't found any direct help for this.

jobStatus.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".serverSortTB .THSort", function () {
        // This is where I pulled out the code in the file below.

        fn_UpdateSortColumns();

        // Other code here to notify the Controller of the changes.
    });
}
```

filterSortBase.js

```
function fn_UpdateSortColumns() {
    $('.serverSortTB').find('.THSort').not(this).each(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("sorting_desc")) {
            $(this).removeClass("sorting_desc").addClass("sorting");

        }
        if ($(this).hasClass("sorting_asc")) {
            $(this).removeClass("sorting_asc").addClass("sorting");

        }
    });

    var s = $(this);
    if (s.hasClass("sorting_asc")) {

        s.removeClass("sorting_asc").addClass("sorting_desc");
    } else if (s.hasClass("sorting_desc")) {

        s.removeClass("sorting_desc").addClass("sorting_asc");
    } else {

        s.removeClass("sorting").addClass("sorting_asc");
    }
}
```

Both .js files are scripts in the Index.html file. Using the debugger I see the fun_UpdateSortColumns getting called and can step through it.

Comment: Your problem is `this` object, Its not refereeing to element which you are expecting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `this` inside your `fn_UpdateSortColumns()` function points to the call context of the function. Since you called it like this:

```
function () {
    fn_UpdateSortColumns();
```

the call has no call context, so `this` is probably global scope.

You could either pass `this` into your function:

```
function () {
    fn_UpdateSortColumns(this);
```

or use `.call()` to apply the correct context:

```
function () {
    fn_UpdateSortColumns.call(this);
```

Comment: You really shouldn't use fn_UpdateSortColumns.call(this), while it will work the fundamental issue behind the scope change is that the function is declared in the global scope.